# Using "Perhaps" in a hypothesis

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, adverbs

Hypothesis: "Perhaps It will not snow tomorrow

My friend reasoned that a hypothesis has to be a declarative statement, and by using "perhaps" I am calling into question the truth of the hypothesis, and thus it cannot be a hypothesis.

So can "perhaps" be used in a declarative sentence? And can it be used in a hypothesis?

Comment: The hypothesis is the declaration; labelling it a hypothesis means that no assertion as to the truth value of the statement is true. Your hypothesis could be 'It will snow tomorrow', 'It will not snow tomorrow', 'All rose flowers have the same number of petals' etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the hypotheses I've written (mostly scientific or reasearch -based), you want to avoid the use of suggestive terms like 'perhaps' or 'possibly'. Using a word like 'perhaps' doesn't offer any insight into how you're going to test your hypothesis, which should be written in an "if-then" format. You set up a tentative relationship. Like this:

"**If** I play the lottery, **then** I will get rich."

In this prediction, a tentative relationship is stated: **"if"** the frequency of winning is related to frequency of buying lottery tickets. **"then"** is followed by a prediction of what will happen if you increase or decrease the frequency of buying lottery tickets.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps can be used for rhetorical purposes that are not necessarily logical. The obvious quotation is Winston Churchill "Now, this is not the end. It is not even the beginning of the end. But it is, perhaps, the end of the beginning."

If you move away from the rhetorical world to, perhaps, that of statistics, or science more generally, then, of course, the hypothesis that you test has to be a definite hypothesis. But if you are testing it, that means that it is not necessarily true. Perhaps it is not true.